# How to Optimize MySQL Database Queries for Complex Reporting?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I'm working on a web application that involves generating complex reports from a MySQL database. The reports involve multiple joins, aggregates, and filtering conditions, and they're becoming increasingly slow as the data grows.
I'm using the following query as an example:

```
SELECT
    customers.name,
    products.product_name,
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS total_quantity,
    SUM(order_items.price) AS total_revenue
FROM
    customers
JOIN
    orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
JOIN
    order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
JOIN
    products ON order_items.product_id = products.id
WHERE
    orders.order_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-08-31'
GROUP BY
    customers.id, products.id
```

This query takes a considerable amount of time to execute, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. I've already added indexes to relevant columns, but the performance is still not satisfactory.

Are there any advanced optimization techniques or best practices I should consider when dealing with such complex reporting queries in MySQL? Should I denormalize the data or consider using materialized views? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

- The MySQL version I'm using is 8.0.
- The tables involved have appropriate indexes on the columns used for joins and filtering.
- The application framework I'm using is Node.js with the mysql2 library for database connectivity.

I've spent significant time researching and experimenting with different approaches, but I'm still struggling with query performance. Any advice or examples of how to handle similar scenarios would be incredibly valuable. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of saying _"have appropriate indexes"_, start by including the DDL for each table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`), index statistics (`SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name`) and `EXPLAIN` output for your existing query.

Comment: You could try summing the orders table first in an inner query before joining in the dimension tables in the outer query.  If that makes no difference then the optimizer has already spotted that and is effectively  doing that for you.  In that case the summarization is intrinsically slow and you'll need to attack that.  One way you can help the optimizer spot that possibility is to change your group by variables to the order table customer_id and product_id.

Comment: You could use www.eversql.com Free Trial (30 day limit) to get this one query analyzed and ensure your query will be high performance.  Observation only - not representing the site.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer, aggregating in subquery before joining will also give the correct result, which should be considered at least as important as performance.

Comment: you could also consider materialized views which get refreshed every 15 minutes hour assumming that is acceptable for reporting time period: https://linuxhint.com/materialized-views-mysql/  in essence the query is run in advance of the actual call to run it and results are stored so no joins no indexes needed as the results are pre-calculated.  The issue is they are stagnet up to the time the latest refresh occured.  but you have to generate the process yourself as mySQL doesn't suppor them. but it can be emulated

Comment: can you pls add the **EXPLAIN** of your query in your question. Also you can add the output from **set profiling = ON;
SELECT (your query);
show profile;
set profiling = OFF;** to see witch procedure use the most time

Comment: @Hiro Dublin Until you post the TEXT data requested by user1191247 for each table used and the EXPLAIN SELECT .... we can not verify any table is properly indexed.

Comment: Profiling is usually a waste.  It will probably say one useless thing like "Sending data" for 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

"application framework" -- Thanks for providing the generated SQL.

These composite indexes are likely to help with performance:

```
orders:  INDEX(order_date, customer_id,  id)
order_items:  INDEX(order_id,  quantity, price, product_id)
```

Note how the only table mentioned in the `WHERE` is `orders`.  So, having an index with the relevant columns (`order_date`) will, in this case, speed things up.

"tables involved have appropriate indexes" -- Well, do you have the above indexes?

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT...` to verify that it is starting with `orders` and involving an index.

"materialized views" -- This may be a an optimization.  Each night run a similar query for the previous day's orders.  MySQL 8 does not have any 'automated' materialized queries, but see my discussion of [*Summary Tables*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

As some of the Comments mentioned, do the `GROUPing` and/or `LIMITing` before any `JOIN` that are happening more than necessary.  I'm referring to getting the names repeatedly, only to boil them down with the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT  c.name, p.product_name, 
        sums.total_quantity, sums.total_revenue
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  SUM(oi.quantity) AS total_quantity,
                  SUM(oi.price) AS total_revenue,
                  o.customer_id,
                  oi.product_id
            FROM  orders AS o
            JOIN  order_items AS oi  ON o.id = oi.order_id
            WHERE  o.order_date >= '2023-01-01'
              AND  o.order_date <  '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL 8 MONTH
            GROUP BY  o.customer_id, oi.product_id 
        ) AS sums
    JOIN  products AS p  ON oi.product_id = p.id
    JOIN  customers AS c  ON c.id = o.customer_id
```